# How to avoid cast of return value in entity framework on an error being returned from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am invoking a stored procedure through Entity framework command. 
On the success case, it returns a list as expected as I am selecting the guid from a table as a result.

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
```

However in the error case(validation) the stored procedure returns -1 early without selecting the guids in the table. hence upon executing the above EF statement, it causes the below error

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

Is there a way to avoid the cast to guid on a error condition (I'm returning error message as a output variable from stored proc)

How this error case in SP is usually handled

Comment: Do you use the BEGIN TRY and BEGIN CATCH syntax in your SP to handle errors? if your SP throws exception (even manually triggered exception) then you will be able to catch in your .net code?

Comment: @Thangadurai - went with your approach to get that done. Thanks.